# Moving VC++ Project from .NET 4.0 to 4.5?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to move my VC++ project from .NET 4.0 to 4.5. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Using online guides I thought the only change I had to do was edit the .vcxproj file to add this line for **TargetFrameworkVersion**:

```
<Project ...>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion> 
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

After making this change the properties inspector correctly lists target framework version as 4.5 now. However, when I try to load the VC++ assembly in my C# .NET 4.5 application I get a **BadImageFormatException**:

[image]

What  could be causing this exception? Am I missing some additional steps to move the VC++ project to ,NET 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this has nothing to do with .NET framework version -- you wouldn't get `BadImageFormatException` for mismatches there. .NET 4.5 can load earlier .NET framework assemblies.

More likely your C# application is running as x86 but you compiled the C++/CLI project as x64 or vice versa. Check that the bitness of the projects you're building match.

Note that the default bitness for C# changed in Visual Studio 2010; so if you are converting a project older than that you may have had `<Prefer32Bit>` turned on for your C# application, which would cause it to run as x86 even on x64 computers. Note that it is impossible to make an AnyCPU C++/CLI application (assuming you didn't use `/clr:pure`), so if your C# application depends on the C++/CLI component it's probably best to mark the C# application with the same bitness rather than AnyCPU.

Comment: I have my C# marked as Any CPU and the VC++ project set at x64. This setup worked up until I moved from 4.0 to 4.5 .NET Framework. I am building and running on a 64-bit machine. How can I check that the C# executables are running in 64-bit or not to confirm your theory?

Comment: Check your caproj for "Prefer32Bit"

Comment: Confirmed that none of them have the Prefer32Bit flag.

Comment: @StickFigs: Looks like they changed it to the default: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/

Comment: @StickFigs: You should not build a program as AnyCPU that depends on non-AnyCPU components.

Comment: Corflags.exe confirms that my C# application has "32BITPREF : 1" set. How can I turn this off?

Comment: @StickFigs: You should build your C# application as x64 because it depends on x64 components. (That will automatically turn `<Prefer32Bit>` off of course) Alternately, add `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` to your `.csproj`. Note that if you do this your app will fail on x86 machines.

Comment: Set 'Prefer32Bit' to false on all of my C# executable projects and now it loads the VC++ assembly without issue! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your solution ... go to Properties .... click Build...  check your Platform Target...  make sure it matches for every solution in your project

If your project has different Platform Targets, this exception is thrown.

If the Platform Target is set for x86, make sure all of them are set for x86 in each solution.

If the Platform Target is set for x64, make sure all of them are set for x64 in each solution.

Comment: Just checked, all of them are targeting .NET 4.5

Comment: Not that.... check the `Platform Target` in the `Build` section.  You are looking at the `Target Framework` in the `Application` section, which is not correct.  Check my edit

Comment: My C# projects are targeting Any CPU while the VC++ project is targeting x64. I am building and running on a 64-bit machine. This setup worked up until I switched all projects to .NET 4.5.

Comment: In your VC++ project make sure all of your solutions are targeting to x64.  The compiler doesn't play well, if they are not all set to the same target

Comment: My solution is 100+ C# projects with the VC++ project being the only VC++ project in the whole solution.

Comment: oh.  I see now. hmmm, not sure about that